# Drop Box Application for BB-z10

Tags: cascade, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

i have developed an application that iterate through all the files in "/accounts/" folder and open file for some specific need,but when i try to run the app it starts downloading images from box application why so?

Answer (score 1):

The Dropbox and Box cloud folders appear to be mounted to folders in the local BB10 file system under shared/Dropbox and shared/Box. I assume that the contents of those folders are downloaded the moment they are accessed.